# Apply a filter as an attribute of a directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I have a custom filter that I need to add to the inner span of a directive and all of the examples of using a filter as an attr in the directive have not worked for me. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Directive:

```
import angular from 'angular';

function userName() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            user: '=',
            dataFilter: '@'
        },
        template: require('./user-name.pug'),
        link: function($scope, $el, $attr, $filter) {
            let filter = $filter($attr['dataFilter']);
        }
    }
}

export default angular.module('directives.username', [])
    .directive('userName', userName)
    .name;
```

html:

```
<user-name user="vm.user" dataFilter="ellipsisMaxLength:20" class="layout-align-center-center layout-row">
    <!-- ngIf: user.display_name -->
    <!-- ngIf: !user.display_name -->
    <span ng-if="!user.display_name" class="ng-binding ng-scope">Person McPersonson</span>
    <!-- end ngIf: !user.display_name -->
</user-name>
```

I want the filter to be applied to the inner text of the span. I cannot add the filter directly to the template.

Thank you!

Comment: do you want to apply height to span tag?

Comment: no the filter shortens the length of the text ("Person McPersonson") and adds ellipsis so it would look like "Person McP..."

Comment: `$scope.myfilter = $filter($attr['dataFilter']); <span>{{myfilter('Person McPersonson')}}</span>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get span tag and have to add style to it something like this

```
link: function($scope, $el, $attr, $filter) {
        let filter = $filter($attr['dataFilter']);
        var span = $el.first();
        span.css('text-overflow','ellipsis');
        span.css('overflow','hidden');
        span.css('white-space','nowrap');
    }
```